# Django for Data Tables to group by when coloumn hidden

Tags: html, django, datatable, datatables, yui-datatable

**Question:**
I have a Data table displaying on django , but now I like to group by when ever I will hide the coloumn

column1 column2 column3

AAA       CAD   25

AAA       USD   12

BBB       CAD   13

BBB       USD   16

CCC       CAD   11

CCC       USD   18

The above table will be displayed on web page using Django, now when ever I hide **coloumn2** It should group by and  display like below table

**column1**   **column3**
AAA                37

BBB                29

CCC                39

when ever  I unhide it again it should display same as first table again.

can anyone tell me there is any possible way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your models and template code here to make query?

Comment: models.py: DDAFULL(models.Model):
     
     LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE=models.CharField(max_length=50,db_column='LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE', primary_key=False)
     CUR=models.CharField(max_length=5)
     SIC_CODE=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=0)
     LCR_NONOP_INS=models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
     LCR_OP_INS=models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
     LCR_NONOP_UNINS=models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)
     LCR_OP_UNINS=models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)

Comment: views.py            cursor1.execute('''SELECT *
INTO table1
FROM
(select dummy as LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE,CUR AS CURRENCY,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_INS))) as LCR_NONOP_INS, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_OP_INS))) as LCR_OP_INS, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_UNINS))) as LCR_NONOP_UNINS, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_OP_UNINS))) as LCR_OP_UNINS
from (select *,(case when LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE='Corporate' then 'Non-Credit Financial Entities'
else LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE
end) as dummy from   table0) a
group by CUR,dummy) tab1
''')

Comment: The table is displaying fine...but it should grouped by other columns on web page when ever I hide a column... @hardik Patel